# dependable drop down menu by parsing json

Tags: php, json, drop-down-menu

i have got a json similar to this ,i am wondering how to parse the following json for organisation,location and building as dependable drop downs 
the json is as follows

```
 [{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"},{"location":[{"building":["test_loc1_building1","test_loc1_building2"],"name":"test location1"},{"building":["test_loc2_building2"],"name":"test location2"}],"name":"test Organization"}]
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse JSON, or how to style and script a drop-down menu?

Comment: i have already parsed it but not getting all the locations and building from the json here is my code http://pastebin.com/XjXHe3Lc